# injecting the correct type to my business class using Autofac

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, autofac, ooad

I currently have a business class whose constructor takes in a repository implementation. There are multiple implementations of this repository. At runtime I want to decide which repository implementation should be supplied. I am new to using DI frameworks and also Autofac. Here are my repository implementations.

```
public interface IRepository
{
  string GetData();
}

public class ServiceRepository : IRepository
{
  ///implementation..
}

public class DatabaseRepository : IRepository
{
  ///implementation..
}



public class BusinessClass
{
   public BusinessClass(IRepository repo)
   {
     //assign to local variable
   }
}
```

As you can see, IRepository has multiple implementations. I would however like to decide at runtime which one should be passed in to my business class. I went thru these examples [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) and [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html), but they dont seem to explain how to achieve this requirement. Changing the interface design is not an option at this point. Do I still need to implement a factoryclass to selectively resolve the correct type?

Comment: You register the implementation you want when the app starts based on config files or whatever plugin system if you have one. If you need to change things "on the fly" (which IMO it's a bit smelly) then you need a factory.

Comment: why would be a bit smelly? not contradicting what you are saying, but just trying to understand why. This business class depends on external services for data. The front end will send it the data source based on the user's selection. Sometimes it could be webservice-A. At other times it could be webservice-B, still other times it could be a database. Duplicating the business class for each of these selections just so Autofac has just one class to resolve seems like we are wetting the DRYness of existing code to suit a DI framework. Needless to say the services are not in my control to change.

Comment: Then your business service should take a factory as  dependency, and that factory would be injected by autofac.

Answer (score 0):

There are several cleaner ways of doing it rather than using a factory.

- You could use the Chain of Responsibility pattern where you resolve all IRepositories using Autofac and then each repository can tell you whether they are responsible to handle that request.
- You could turn this on it's head and say, well I have a list of repositories, I need a service which takes these repositories and returns one specific one depending on a set of business rules (essentially a factory).  Although this approach makes the solution a bit unit-test-friendly.

Just some options for you to consider :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Factory pattern here, but you do not need to create a dedicated factory class, Func will be enough. Your business layer should not be aware of this switching logic, it should go to application layer controller.

One possible example:

Your controller

```
public void SomeController(Func<string, IBusinessService> serviceFactory)
{
    this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
}
...
//somewhere inside controller
serviceFactory("database").SomeBusinessLogic();
...
```

and Autofac registration:

```
builder
.RegisterType<ServiceRepository>()
.Named<IRepository("service");

builder
.RegisterType<DatabaseRepository>()
.Named<IRepository>("database");

builder
.Register<Func<string,IBusinessService>>(cx =>
{
    var componentContext = cx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return (key =>
        new BusinessService(componentContex.ResolveNamed<IRepository>(key))
    );
}
)
.As<Func<string, IBusinessService>>();
```